# How To Encrypt Pidgin account Passwords

Tags: password, pidgin

we know that pidgin stores password in plaintext in this file:

```
/home/username/.purple/accounts.xml
```

is there any way to encrypt passwords stored in this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gnome keyring plugin, as the name describes it only works with the Gnome Keyring.

You can build it from source:

https://github.com/aebrahim/pidgin-gnome-keyring

Or use a PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-gnome-keyring/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

This is a still valid post that describes how it works and how to install it:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/save-pidgin-passwords-in-gnome-keyring.html